# iis 8 url rewrite https and www

Tags: iis, https, url-rewriting, http-host

I need to make the following redirects and I can't get the last one:

- http://www.example.com
- http://example.com
- https;//example.com ** Not working - get 404

all have to go to:

- https;//www.example.com

(Note: the semicolons are actually colons)

The first two are taken care of with a condition "{HTTPS} Matches off" but I'm trying to get the last one working with either {HTTP_HOST} or {URL} and nothing is happening.

What condition will work for me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two conditions:

```
<conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" />
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.com$" />
</conditions>
```

In IIS Manager it looks like that:

[image]

**UPDATE**

Based on our discussion in comments:

```
<rule name="All in one URL" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\." negate="true" />
     </conditions>
     <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com:35077{URL}" />
 </rule>
```

Comment: Unless this is a separate rule, I can't see how it would work. I'm trying to push non-https requests to https. So my rule that is working is {HTTPS}=off redirect to https;//www.example.com and it works. 
I was putting in a separate condition in there with Match Any to capture https;//example.com.
Are you suggesting a separate rule altogether?

Comment: When I tried this in a separate rule, it didn't capture the case properly.

Comment: So, do you want single rule, which will redirects `http://www.example.com`, `http://example.com`, `https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com`?

Comment: Yes - exactly. However, if I need to do it with two separate rules, then that would work as well.

Comment: Please check my answer

Comment: It still seems to be failing. Can I send you the specifics to check out?

Comment: you can find my email in my profile. You can send me details by email